# Qt own enum in class

Tags: c++, qt, enums, signals-slots

I want to declare my own enum in a class in Qt and use it for signals and slots, but I get this error.

```
QObject::connect: Cannot queue arguments of type 'ClassA::MyEnum'
(Make sure 'ClassA::MyEnum' is registered using qRegisterMetaType().)
```

This is my source code:

**ClassA.h**

```
public:
    enum MyEnum {
        READING = 0,
        STOPPED = 1,
        FINISHED = 2
    };

signals:
    void changed(QString text, int readTextInPercent, ClassA::MyEnum status);
```

**ClassA.cpp**

```
emit changed(QString("string"), 50, ClassA::READING);
```

**ClassB.h**

```
public slots:
    void changed(QString text, int readTextInPercent, ClassA::MyEnum status);
```

**ClassB.cpp**

```
this->connect(m_ClassA, SIGNAL(changed(QString, int, ClassA::MyEnum)), this, SLOT(changed(QString, int, ClassA::MyEnum)));

void ClassB::changed(QString text, int readTextInPercent, ClassA::MyEnum status) {

}
```

I don't know where and with which parameter I have to put the `qRegisterMetaType`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to do:

`Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(ClassA::MyEnum)`

in your classA.h header.

Then in ClassA constructor (or main() but remember to include classa.h there first):

`qRegisterMetaType<ClassA::MyEnum>("ClassA::MyEnum");`

Then use like:

`connect(whatever, SIGNAL(whatever_uses_myenum(ClassA::MyEnum)), ..., ...)`

Answer (score 4):

The error thrown by Qt is very descriptive:

> Make sure 'ClassA::MyEnum' is registered using qRegisterMetaType()

So you will need to include this line:

```
qRegisterMetaType<ClassA::MyEnum>("ClassA::MyEnum");
```

In any part of your code in which you know it will be called. I use to include the qRegisterMetaType in the main function of my applications. I recommend you to take a look to the Qt Documentation about the topics: qRegisterMetaType & Q_DECLARE_METATYPE.

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid having to call `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE` and `qRegisterMetaType()` by using [Q_ENUM](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#Q_ENUM), which was added in Qt 5.5:

```
public:
    enum MyEnum {
        READING = 0,
        STOPPED = 1,
        FINISHED = 2
    };
    Q_ENUM(MyEnum)
```

Comment: I used Q_ENUM (declared in the public section of class) and still got that, while connecting to a lambda. I'm using fully qualified type name on signal argmument and on lambda capture, `auto` do not seems to work. Put `qRegisterMetaType<ClassA::MyEnum>("ClassA::MyEnum");` on main, just after QApplication app, and it works  even with `auto`. The  `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(ClassA::MyEnum)` was not necessary.